# How to identify if one json contains specific value in json schema

Tags: jsonschema

There is a json result like this below, and I need to check if a specific value is contained in shop_ids, for example, 232323 is contained, while 232324 is not. Is it possible to achieve that with JSON Schema? How?

```
{
    "request":{
        "0":{
            "cids":{
                "0":"a",
                "1":"b",
                "2":"c",
                "3":"d",
                "4":"e",
                "5":"f",
                "6":"g",
                "7":"h"
            },
            "data_type":"1",
            "key_type":"1",
            "one_item_id":"0",
            "queries":{
                "0":{
                    "0":"query1"
                },
                "1":{
                    "0":"query2"
                }
            },
            "shop_ids":{
                "0":"11111",
                "1":"232323",
                "2":"33333",
                "3":"124151",
                "4":"55555",
                "5":"12121"
            },
            "num":"30"
        }
    }
}
```

note: the shop_ids may contain more numeric fields, not just 0-5.

I tried "patternProperties", it does work for checking specific key-value but returns fail on other key-value. What I need is just any of "shop_ids" match the specific value is ok.

Comment: Check the length of your request[0].shop_id, if length > 0 all you have to do is loop through them and use an if statement to determine if the value is equal to whatever you need.

Comment: This is not doable with json schema, unfortunately.